# How do I configure rabbitmq queue via puppet

Tags: rabbitmq, puppet, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm trying to install rabbitmq via puppet. I'm using the [puppetlabs-rabbitmq](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq) module. It also has section to configure queues and exchanges, which are `Native Types`. I can't figure out how to use these native types.

My code for rabbitmq installation:

```
class rabbitmq-concrete{

  $tools = ["vim-enhanced","mc"]
  package { $tools: ensure => "installed" }

  $interface = "enp0s8"
  $address = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar('::ipaddress_${interface}') -%>")

  class { 'rabbitmq':
    config_cluster    => true,
    cluster_nodes     => ['rml01', 'rml02'],
    cluster_node_type => 'disc',
    manage_repos => true,
    node_ip_address => $address,
    erlang_cookie => 'rmq_secret',
  }
    rabbitmq_exchange { "logging@${node_name}":
      type     => 'topic',
      ensure   => present,
    }

    rabbitmq_queue { "logging@${node_name}":
      durable     => true,
      auto_delete => false,
      arguments   => {
        x-message-ttl => 123,
        x-dead-letter-exchange => 'other'
      },
     ensure      => present,
    }

    rabbitmq_binding { "logging@logging@${node_name}":
      destination_type => 'logging',
      routing_key      => '#',
      arguments        => {},
      ensure           => present,
    }
}
include rabbitmq-concrete
```

I get following error:

```
==> rml01: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type rabbitmq_queue at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/manifests/site.pp:35 on node rml01
==> rml01: Wrapped exception:
==> rml01: Invalid resource type rabbitmq_queue
==> rml01: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type rabbitmq_queue at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/manifests/site.pp:35 on node rml01
```

**Note**: When I leave out these native types, rabbit installation works well.

How do I use `Native Types` to configure `rabbitmq_queue`, `rabbitmq_exchange` and `rabbitmq_binding` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the required prerequisites?  You need the following packages from the [Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/):
puppetlabs/stdlib 
stahnma/epel 
nanliu/staging 
garethr/erlang

To your manifest I added:

```
include epel
include staging
class { 'erlang': epel_enable => true}
```

Comment: I'm using librarian-puppet, which is supposed to install all dependencies. Nevertheless I made sure that all stated modules are installed and added the lines to my manifest. Still getting the same error: "Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type rabbitmq_queue"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is dated 13th Feb, yet looking on the Puppet Forge those features were only added to that module in the most recent release on 10th March in version 5.1.0.

Full changelog => https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/rabbitmq/changelog

Abridged:
"2015-03-10 - Version 5.1.0

Summary
This release adds several features for greater flexibility in configuration of rabbitmq, includes a number of bug fixes, and bumps the minimum required version of puppetlabs-stdlib to 3.0.0.

Features

**Add rabbitmq_queue and rabbitmq_binding types**"

Comment: I should have updated the question, but I also tried the source from github, which already had the changes. I was really missing the erlang somehow.