# Error 'invalid parameter include_src' when provisionning RabbitMQ with Puppet on Vagrant

Tags: rabbitmq, vagrant, puppet, git-submodules

I am trying to install the RabbitMQ module on my virtual machine. I used :

`git submodule add https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq.git`

and I installed every dependecy I could find the same way (which are, like listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498132/how-do-i-configure-rabbitmq-queue-via-puppet) : stdlib, epel, staging and erlang).

I reduced my manifest to the bare minimum :

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }


exec { 'apt-get update':
    command => 'apt-get update',
    timeout => 60,
    tries   => 3
}

package { ['python-software-properties']:
    ensure  => 'installed',
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

$sysPackages = [ 'build-essential', 'git', 'curl']
package { $sysPackages:
    ensure => "installed",
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

include epel
include staging
class { 'erlang': epel_enable => true}

class { 'rabbitmq':
    port                    => '5672',
    service_manage          => true,
    environment_variables   => {
        'RABBITMQ_NODENAME'     => 'server',
        'RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME'  => 'rabbitMQ'
    }
}
```

And when I provision my VM with `vagrant provision`, I get the error :

```
==> default: Error: Invalid parameter include_src at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules
-33d06c2339c7ee7ab2bd92b2d11cf5d9/erlang/manifests/repo/apt.pp:39
```

I'm almost certain it is because of a dependency I do not have, but I can not find out which one. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that erlang module requires older version of apt module. Look at this [patch](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/commit/a220dcf08c84208d08d6f96b8aee7c7f70ae83a1). Recently, in apt resource, parameters `include_src` and `include_deb` were substituted by one `include` parameter. To solve the problem please install `apt` module in [version 1.8.0](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt/1.8.0/readme).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm testing this right away.